# Solving a system of complex equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

$$u = (1+i, i), v = (1-i, 2i), w = (2,3+i)$$

I'm asked to find is there's $z$ such that:
$$v = zu$$

So if I suppose $z = a+bi$ I have the system:

$$(1-i, 2i) = (a+bi)(1+i, i)\implies\\(1-i, 2i) = (a-b+(a+b)i, ai-b)$$

then I have the system:

$$1-i = a-b + ai + bi\\2i = ai-b$$

So by the second equation $b = ai-2i$, subtitute it in the first equation to get:

$$1-i = 2i+2$$

So I don't get any solution in terms of $a$ and $b$. Does it means that there is no such $z$ that satifies what was asked? (don't know how to verify it on wolfram alpha)

Comment: I do not understand your notation. Are $u$, $v$, and $w$ ordered pairs of complex numbers? How do they multiply?

Comment: @RoryDaulton sorry, they're ordered pairs, with the most simple multiplication used

Comment: Is $z$ also a pair of complex numbers? Then $z=(-i,2)$ satisfies the relation $v=zu$, as you can find by division. What does $w$ have to do with all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in your notation, you are doing coordinate-wise multiplication in ordered pairs of complex numbers, $v=zu$ leads to

$$z=\frac vu$$
$$=\frac{(1-i,2i)}{(1+i,i)}$$
$$=\left(\frac{1-i}{1-i},\frac{2i}i\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{(1-i)(1-i)}{(1-i)(1+i)}, 2 \right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{1-2i+i^2}{1^2-i^2}, 2 \right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{1-2i-1}{1+1}, 2 \right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{-2i}2, 2 \right)$$
$$=\left(-i, 2 \right)$$

It is easy to check that this $z$ works. Your ordered pair $w$ is not used at all.